# How to get Twitter-Bootstrap navigation to show active link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not understanding how Twitter Bootstrap does active links for the navigation. If I have a regular navigation like this (with ruby on rails linking):

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>
  <li class=""> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>
  <li class=""> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>        
</ul>
```

How do I keep it active based on the link clicked?

Comment: FYI: I use the active_link_to gem and specify {:wrap_class => :li}. This will create: <li class='active'>...</li> when the REQUEST_URI matches the HREF value...

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just made an answer on the very same question here
[Twitter Bootstrap Pills with Rails 3.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862524/twitter-bootstrap-pills-with-rails-3-2-2)

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'controller1' %>"> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'controller2' %>"> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'controller3' %>"> <a href="/link">Link</a> </li>        
</ul>
```

Comment: I think the idea is correct here, but going directly to the params hash seems like a bad idea. Likewise for repeating the same code over and over. I would recommend at least using the current_page? method to check the current controller/action, and would also move the code into a helper to avoid the code repetition.

Comment: I wonder how do I write the same in haml. Converting to haml doesn't work for me. Or perhaps I'm wrong somewhere

Comment: HAML implementation `%li{:class => "#{'active' if current_page?(root_path)}"}=link_to "Home", root_path `

Comment: Is there an elegant way of making this work with friendly_id gem without doing db requests?

Comment: Rails docs recommends the use of `controller_name` and `action_name` helpers instead of accessing them from  the params hash.

Comment: Or another one for HAML: `%li{class: params[:controller].nil? ? 'active' : ''}= link_to 'Home', root_path`

Answer (score 175):

You can use something like (very similar to what @phil mentioned, but a little shorter):

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(about_path) %>"><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(contact_path) %>"><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: doesn't work if you have subnavigation. The path changes but you're in the same section.. makes sense?

Comment: yes, correct, if you want to highlight a menu item no matter what method you are running inside the same controller, you could use @Pierre solution: `'active' if params[:controller] == 'controller1'`

Comment: How can I add more paths or a specific path like `user_*_path` in `<%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>` ?

Comment: How would you add more than one path to make the menu item active? For instance, if you have several items in a dropdown that are components of the same menu item, and you'd like to make the menu item active when you're on any of the pages found in the dropdown menu? Please let us know as soon as possible.

Answer (score 46):

https://github.com/twg/active_link_to

```
<%= active_link_to 'Users', users_path, :wrap_tag => :li %>
```

`#=> <li class="active"><a href="/users">Users</a></li>`

Comment: Love it.  Why rewrite the wheel?

Comment: This should really be the way to go...Unless you don't want to pull in another dependency.

Answer (score 34):

I used a helper to implement this in the style of Rails' form helpers.

In a helper (e.g. `app/helpers/ApplicationHelper.rb`):

```
def nav_bar
  content_tag(:ul, class: "nav navbar-nav") do
    yield
  end
end

def nav_link(text, path)
  options = current_page?(path) ? { class: "active" } : {}
  content_tag(:li, options) do
    link_to text, path
  end
end
```

Then, in a view (e.g. `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`):

```
<%= nav_bar do %>
  <%= nav_link 'Home', root_path %>
  <%= nav_link 'Posts', posts_path %>
  <%= nav_link 'Users', users_path %>
<% end %>
```

This example produces (when on the 'users' page):

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/posts">Posts</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="/users">Users</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks!

Comment: I like this idea, however I'd add a third argument to the nav_link function called html={} that's then passed to link_to.  That way you can pass an html hash to nav_link the same way you'd use link_to normally.

Answer (score 22):

Use this instead to select active link in nav based on the current route without server code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: This is the best solution cause it works with dropdown menus as well, and I include the line ```$('li.active').closest('.dropdown').addClass('active');``` to highlight the parent menu too.

Comment: how to change it to apply for sub-pages also? like http://example.com/home will work. I need link "Home" to be active in case of http://example.com/home/page also.

Answer (score 11):

I've found success using the **logical and** (`&&`) in **haml**:

```
%ul.nav
  %li{class: current_page?(events_path) && 'active'}
    = link_to "Events", events_path
  %li{class: current_page?(about_path) && 'active'}
    = link_to "About Us", about_path
```

Answer (score 5):

For each link:

```
<% if current_page?(home_path) -%><li class="active"><% else -%><li><% end -%>
  <%= link_to 'Home', home_path %>
</li>
```

or even

```
<li <% if current_page?(home_path) -%>class="active"<% end -%>>
  <%= link_to 'Home', home_path %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

not sure if you are asking about how the twitter bootstrap css is used, or the rails side.  I'm assuming the rails side.

if so checkout the [`#link_to_if`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/00554568e0625b2e4d4212ab7464f02234f74427/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L452) method 
or the [`#link_to_unless_current`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/00554568e0625b2e4d4212ab7464f02234f74427/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L396) method

Answer (score 3):

Today I had the same question/problem but with an other approach for the solution.
I create a helper function in application_helper.rb:

```
def navMainAktiv(actionName)
    if params[:action] == actionName    
    "active"
    end
end
```

and the link looks like this:

```
<li class="<%= navMainAktiv('about')%>"><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
```

You can replace `params[:action]` with `params[:controller]` and set your controller name in the link.

Answer (score 3):

**Basic, No Helper**

```
<%= content_tag(:li, class: ('active' if request.path == '/contact')) do %>
    <%= link_to 'Contact', '/contact' %>
<% end %>
```

I use this since I have more than one class -

```
<%= content_tag(:li, class: (request.path == '/contact' ? 'active black' : 'black')) do %>
    <%= link_to 'Contact', '/contact' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This will work for any sub navigation also...just use the parent request path in the sub link.

Answer (score 2):

I use this for each `li`:

`<li><%= link_to_unless_current('Home', root_path) {  link_to('Home', root_path, class: 'active') } %></li>`

Comment: Class needs to be set for `li` not `a`

Answer (score 2):

You may define a helper method in `application_helper.rb`

```
def create_link(text, path)
  class_name = current_page?(path) ? 'active' : ''

  content_tag(:li, class: class_name) do
    link_to text, path
  end
end
```

Now you can use like:

`create_link 'xyz', any_path` which would render as

```
<li class="active">
  <a href="/any">xyz</a>
</li>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did:

I created a ViewsHelper and included in ApplicationController:

```
include ViewsHelper
```

Inside ViewsHelper I created a simple method like this:

```
def page_state(path)
  current_page?(path) ? 'active' : ''
end
```

In my view I do this:

```
<li class="<%= page_state(foobar_path) %>"><%= link_to 'Foobars', foobar_path %></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it yourself by manipulating CSS classes. That is, if a user clicks on some link, then do something (target action), set previous link inactive and new link active.

If your links take you to the server (that is, make page reload), then you can just render active link correctly on the server. Otherwise, if you're doing some client-side stuff (switching tab panes or whatever), you have to use javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you could use [tabulous](https://github.com/techiferous/tabulous) for the links

article [here](http://rubysource.com/too-good-to-be-true-twitter-bootstrap-meets-formtastic-and-tabulous/) on how to combine tabulous with twitter bootstrap and rails 3.x

Answer (score 1):

I wrote simple helper method using build in view helper `current_page?` when you can specify custom `class` name in `html_options` hash.

```
def active_link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
  active_class = html_options[:active] || "active"
  html_options.delete(:active)
  html_options[:class] = "#{html_options[:class]} #{active_class}" if current_page?(options)
  link_to(name, options, html_options, &block)
end
```

Examples (when you are on `root_path` route):

```
<%= active_link_to "Main", root_path %>
# <a href="/" class="active">Main</a>

<%= active_link_to "Main", root_path, class: "bordered" %>
# <a href="/" class="bordered active">Main</a>

<%= active_link_to "Main", root_path, class: "bordered", active: "disabled" %>
# <a href="/" class="bordered disabled">Main</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers here have things that will work, or partial answers. I combined a bunch of things to make this rails helper method I use:

```
# helper to make bootstrap3 nav-pill <li>'s with links in them, that have
# proper 'active' class if active. 
#
# the current pill will have 'active' tag on the <li>
#
# html_options param will apply to <li>, not <a>. 
#
# can pass block which will be given to `link_to` as normal. 
def bootstrap_pill_link_to(label, link_params, html_options = {})
  current = current_page?(link_params)

  if current
    html_options[:class] ||= ""
    html_options[:class] << " active "
  end

  content_tag(:li, html_options) do
    link_to(label, link_params)
  end      
end
```

It could be made even fancier with argument checking to support `&block` on the link_to etc.

Answer (score 1):

Many answers already, but here is what I wrote to get Bootstrap Icons working with active link. Hope It will help someone

This helper will give you:

1. li element with link containing custom text
2. Optional Bootstrap3 Icon
3. will turn active when you're on the right page

Put this in your application_helper.rb

```
def nav_link(link_text, link_path, icon='')
  class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''
  icon_class = "glyphicon glyphicon-" + icon

  content_tag(:li, :class => class_name) do
    (class_name == '') ? (link_to content_tag(:span, " "+link_text, class: icon_class), link_path)
    : (link_to content_tag(:span, " "+link_text, class: icon_class), '#')
  end
end
```

And use link:

```
<%= nav_link 'Home', root_path, 'home'  %>
```

Last argument is optional - it will add icon to the link. Use names of glyph icons. 
If you want icon with no text:

```
    <%= nav_link '', root_path, 'home'  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you need to implement a navigation system. If it's complex, it might get pretty ugly and pretty fast.

In this case, you might want to use a plugin that can handle that. You could use [navigasmic](https://github.com/jejacks0n/navigasmic) or [simple navigation](https://github.com/andi/simple-navigation/) (I would recommend navigasmic because it keeps the main layer in a view, where it belongs, and not in some configuration)

Answer (score 0):

### Shortest code

This deals with BOTH nav, and sub nav list elements. You can pass either an array a single path and will deal with both.

#### application_helper

```
# Active page method
def ap(p:);'active' if p.class == Array ? p.map{|m| current_page? m}.any? : (current_page? p) end
```

#### view (html.erb)

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="<%= ap p: home_path %>">Home</li>
  <li class="<%= ap p: account_path %>">Account</li>

  <li class="dropdown <%= ap p: [users_path, new_user_path] %>">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Users</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li class="<%= ap p: users_path %>">Users</li>
      <li class="<%= ap p: new_user_path %>">Add user</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ruby on Sinatra ..

I m using bootstrap bare theme, here is the sample navbar code. Note the class name of the element -> .nav - as this is referred in java script.

```
/ Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling
    #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
      %ul.nav.navbar-nav
        %li
          %a{:href => "/demo/one"} Page One
        %li
          %a{:href => "/demo/two"} Page Two
        %li
          %a{:href => "/demo/three"} Page Three
```

in the view page (or partial) add this :javascript, this needs to be executed every time page loads.

haml view snippet ->

```
- content_for :javascript do
  :javascript
      $(function () {
          $.each($('.nav').find('li'), function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('active',
                  $(this).find('a').attr('href') == window.location.pathname);
          });
      });
```

In the javascript debugger make sure you have value of 'href' attribute matches with window.location.pathname. This is slightly different than the solution by @Zitrax which helped me fixing my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
  def active_navigation?(controllers_name, actions_name)
   'active' if controllers_name.include?(controller_name) && actions_name.include?(action_name)
  end
```

slim

```
li class=(active_navigation?(['events'], ['index', 'show'])) = link_to t('navbar.events'), events_path
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```html
          <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>" >
            <%= link_to 'Home', root_path, class:"nav-link"%>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(tools_path) %>" >
            <%= link_to 'Tools', tools_path, class:"nav-link" %>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Request a new tool</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(home_about_path) %>" >
            <%= link_to 'About us', home_about_path, class:"nav-link"%>
          </li>
```

The code inside the `<%= %>` is just `ruby`, and the `=` means that the result of that code will be displayed on the HTML.Do this for every option you want to add in your navbar and it should work fine.