# Bootstrap dynamic active navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, haml

I'm using this code for my navigation:

```
.row-fluid
    .span3
      .well
        %ul.nav.nav-tabs.nav-stacked
          %li.nav-header
            Menu
          %li
            %a{:href => "/cms/1"} page1
          %li
            %a{:href => "/cms/2"} page2
          %li
            %a{:href => "/cms/3"} page3
          %li
            %a{:href => "/cms/4"} page4
```

if i put `.active` after the `%li` it makes the item active, how can i do this dynamically so it reflects which page is currently active? I have all the bootstrap javascript files installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper function like this:

```
def active_navigation(item, param)
  "class='active'" if params[param] == item
end
```

And then in your view, you put something like this:

```
%li.nav-header
  Menu
%li{:class => active_navigation(1, :id)}
  %a{:href => "/cms/1"} page1
%li{:class => active_navigation(2, :id)}
  %a{:href => "/cms/2"} page2
%li{:class => active_navigation(3, :id)}
  %a{:href => "/cms/3"} page3
%li{:class => active_navigation(4, :id)}
  %a{:href => "/cms/4"} page4
```

I just don't know/hate `haml`, so i don't think the syntax is correct. But i do think that this is a good example that you can try to adjust to your own domain.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to get Twitter-Bootstrap navigation to show active link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879169/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-navigation-to-show-active-link) .

In that question there are a lot of alternatives to "autodetect" the current page, and therefore easily set the active class on the related menu item.