# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs active class toggle not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using Twitter bootstrap nav tabs and nav pills. This is my html code:

```
<div class="Header2" style="background-color:#1E3848">
    <div id="headerTab">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active ans-tab"> <a href="http://myweb.com/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="topTab"><a href="http://myweb.com/score/">Score</a></li>
            <li class="topTab"><a href="http://myweb.com/leaderboards/">Leaderboards</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="subHeaderTabPlayer">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"> <a href="http://myweb.com/">Top</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://myweb.com/rules/" data-toggle="pill">Rules</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://myweb.com/player/" data-toggle="pill">Player</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://myweb.com/categories/" data-toggle="pill">Categories</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now if I add attribute `data-toggle="pill"` and  `data-toggle="tab"` the tab with active class change to one which I have clicked. However, `href` is no longer working. 
If I do not use these classes, `href` works but active class does not change and it always stays to the element that class was given at the load of page.

I even tried using jQuery to toggle class behavior and it does not work as well. My script code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        document.getElementById( 'subHeaderTabPlayer' ).style.display = 'none';
        $('ul.nav-tabs li a').click(function (e) {
            var activeTab= document.getElementByClass('active');
            activeTab.removeAttribute("class");

            $('ul.nav-tabs li.active').removeClass('active')
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
        })
        $('ul.nav-pills li a').click(function (e) {
            $('ul.nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
        })
        $(".ans-tab").click(function() {
            document.getElementById('subHeaderTabPlayer').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('subHeaderTabPlayer' ).style.display = 'block';
        });
        $(".topTab").click(function() {
            document.getElementById('subHeaderTabPlayer').style.visibility = 'collapse';
            document.getElementById('subHeaderTabPlayer' ).style.display = 'none';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In my case, the problem was that I had a div after                 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">. So reading your post helped me to solve this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Bootstrap nav tabs and pills work with a JS plugin. The plugin is loaded on the page and takes care of the highlighting and the remembering of the currently active tab or pill. It disables the href attributes if they link to other pages, simply because when you click on a link to another page, a new page is loaded. The JS is then reloaded for this new page, and it does not know about which tab or pill is currently active. They are designed to work with single page apps or links to anchors on the same page, and they work fine for that purpose.

The jQuery approach fails for the same reason, but might be easier to explain.

```
$('ul.nav-pills li a').click(function (e) {
  $('ul.nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
})
```

You click on a link, JS goes off and changes the class, only if it has enough time to do so before the next page is loaded, this next page is loaded because the href attribute on the link tells the browser to navigate to a new page. And the new page loads your JS again, it can't possibly remember the variables from the previous page, like which tab or pill is meant to be active.

If you are going to navigate to other pages, you might as well just set the active class on the right tab for the specific page that is being loaded.

If you really need to do this on the client side, you could do something like this, and load it on each page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Set BaseURL
  var baseURL = 'http://myweb.com/'

  // Get current URL and replace baseURL
  var href = window.location.href.replace(baseURL, '');

  // Remove trailing slash
  href = href.substr(-1) == '/' ? href.substr(0, href.length - 1) : href;

  // Get last part of current URL
  var page = href.substr(href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

  // Add trailing slash if not empty (empty means we're currently at baseURL)
  page = page != '' ? page + '/' : page;

  // Select link based on href attribute and set it's closest 'li' to 'active'. 
  // .siblings('.active').removeClass() is only needed if you have a default 'active li'.
  $('a[href="' + baseURL + page + '"]', '.nav li').closest('li').addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass();

});
```

It sets the active tab based on the last part of the URL, it's kind of specific to your scenario (and previously my scenario) though. You'd have to adapt it if there were file extensions or query parameters involved. Every page needs to at least have a link to itself on it. And it preferably has the exact same header with the same tabs and pills rendered on it as all the other pages.

Both of these last points again raise the thought in my mind "if you have to have this much control over what exactly is being rendered onto the page, you probably have access to the server side", and if that is the case, you might as well fix it there, as every link does a new request to the server anyway. And your solution wouldn't have to rely on some not so robust JavaScript to work.

So this is what I had going at one stage, you could improve it, or implement a solution where you post some data to the next page and read it with JavaScript there (which would probably be easier and more robust if you had file extensions or query strings to deal with).

Good luck with it! :)

Comment: The hint is in the last sentence. JS isn't the place for storing things that need to be remembered across a number of pages. You could implement an approach where your JS takes over the navigating instead of the links, and then posts some values to the new page. But if you are going to be navigating between actual pages, it is a much better idea to just have some server side logic decide which tab or pill is going to have the `active` class before it sends the page to the client. Or if they are static pages, just add the active class to the right tab or pill for every page.

Comment: May be i can send a get or post in the hyperlink. And on my pages check for the parameters to make a class active. right ?

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I would personally only go for that approach if I could not in any way manipulate the server side code or HTML before it is sent to the client.

Comment: I might give a shot to this by changing class in template files for every page associated. Thanks. But i think there must be some way already. someone must have already faced this issue.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I faced the issue myself once, then I built myself a fix, and then realised it was much easier to fix it on the server side. I'll explain what I did to fix it in the answer, since you're pushing for it :)

Comment: That would be really awesome. Thanks a lot Man. :)

Comment: This won't work with multiple sets of tabs (single page apps for example).  See my answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: @kwtco - I understand what you mean, but you aren't answering OP's question. The question is about how to make it work on the client-side **with** a page reload when clicking on the tab, and then getting the right tab to be highlighted. If you had read my answer you would understand that I do not advocate this approach, and I explain that an approach like the one you are suggesting is a better option. But OP insists it needs to be done **with** the page reload, I then provided an answer to OP's specific needs. Your answer is specific to a single page app, which is not what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Something to consider: If each li element uses a different controller, here's something you could try.

[How to get Twitter-Bootstrap navigation to show active link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879169/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-navigation-to-show-active-link)

Your code could look something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'home' %>"> <a href="link" data-toggle="pill">Top</a></li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'rules' %>"><a href="link" data-toggle="pill">Rules</a></li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'player' %>"><a href="link" data-toggle="pill">Player</a></li>
  <li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller] == 'categories' %>"><a href="link" data-toggle="pill">Categories</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This example worked for me:

```
$leftBlock.on("click", "#navFinished", function(){
  $('ul.nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

While this example did not work

```
$leftBlock.on("click", "#navFinished", function(){
  $('ul.nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active')
  $(this).parent('li').addClass('active')
})
```

Removing .parent("li") helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more generalized client side solution using jQuery.  It only assumes that your tabs have the data-toggle attribute and each group of tabs is wrapped in some kind of container element.

```
$('[data-toggle="tab"],[data-toggle="pill"]').click(function() { 
    $(this).parent().children('.active[data-toggle="tab"],.active[data-toggle="pill"]').removeClass('active'); 
    $(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed @syeh solution and got it right. Below is a snippet of my code.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
   <li <?php if (strchr($this->pageTitle,' Job') === ' Job') echo 'class=active';?>><?php echo CHtml::link('JOBS', array('Job/index'));?></li>
   <li <?php if (strchr($this->pageTitle,'Artisan') === 'Artisan') echo 'class=active';?>><?php echo CHtml::link('ARTISANS', array('Artisan/index'));?></li>
   <li <?php if (strchr($this->pageTitle,'Task') === 'Task') echo 'class=active';?>><?php echo CHtml::link('TASKS',array('Task/index'));?></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue: when clicked, tabs would become active but would not properly remove the `active` class from other tabs (i.e. every tab the user clicked on a pageview would have the `active` class).

Switching from an `<ol>` to a `<ul>` made the tabs behave properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function activate($uri) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $uri) {
        echo ' class="active" ';
    }
}

?>

<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li role="tab" <?php activate('/wikireport/index.php'); ?> ><a href="index.php" aria-controls="Home">Wiki Report</a></li>
      <li role="tab" <?php activate('/wikireport/examples.php'); ?> ><a href="examples.php" aria-controls="Examples">Examples</a></li>
      <li role="tab" <?php activate('/wikireport/about.php'); ?> ><a href="about.php" aria-controls="About">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And then in the "content" file, just require/include your navline.php

```
<?php 
include('navline.php'); 
?>
```