# Changing the active class of a link with the twitter bootstrap css in python/flask

Tags: python, class, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2

I got the following html snippet from my page `template.html`.

```
<ul class='nav'>
    <li class="active"><a href='/'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='/lorem'>Lorem</a></li>

    {% if session['logged_in'] %}
        <li><a href="/account">Account</a></li>
        <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a>
        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% if not session['logged_in'] %}
        <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

As you can see on line 2, there's the class active. This highlights the active tab with the twitter bootstrap css file. Now, this will work fine if I would visit `www.page.com/` but not when I would visit `www.page.com/login` for example. It would still highlight the home link as the active tab.

Of course, I could easily do this with Javascript/jQuery but I'd rather not use that in this situation.

There's already a [working solution for ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879169/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-navigation-to-show-active-link) but I don't know how to convert that into python/jinja (I'm rather new to jinja/flask, never worked with ruby at all)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Have you looked at this ? https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/tricks/#highlighting-active-menu-items

### Highlighting Active Menu Items

Often you want to have a navigation bar with an active navigation item. This is really simple to achieve. Because assignments outside of blocks in child templates are global and executed before the layout template is evaluated it’s possible to define the active menu item in the child template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% set active_page = "index" %}
```

The layout template can then access `active_page`. Additionally it makes sense to define a default for that variable:

```
{% set navigation_bar = [
    ('/', 'index', 'Index'),
    ('/downloads/', 'downloads', 'Downloads'),
    ('/about/', 'about', 'About')
] -%}

{% set active_page = active_page|default('index') -%}
...
<ul id="navigation">
    {% for href, id, caption in navigation_bar %}
    <li{% if id == active_page %} class="active"{% endif
    %}><a href="{{ href|e }}">{{ caption|e }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: That's plain beautiful, especially after seeing the ruby code, this makes so much more sense. I had no idea this was even possible with jinja, thanks for the link as well, I'm sure I can figure this out now :)

Comment: why escape `href` and `caption` (e.g. `href|e`) when you already control the values?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I don't know actually how it gets the current page name, so I modified your code to be like this:
`{% if request.endpoint == id %}`...
the rest of the code is the same.  But I'm curious about how does your snippest know the endpoint and do the comparsion.

Comment: @adonese it is working, don't forget to set active_page in every template ex: `contacts, about, works` etc.

Comment: @Nicholas is right and it's what I did with my little project.  This trick works like a champ.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant, would upvote 10 times if I could, thank you!

Answer (score 35):

Here is another simpler way if you have menus distributed all over the page. This way uses inline if statements to print out the class **active**.

```
<ul>

<li class="{{ 'active' if active_page == 'menu1' else '' }}">
<a href="/blah1">Link 1</a>
</li>

<li class="{{ 'active' if active_page == 'menu2' else '' }}">
<a href="/blah2"> Link 2 </a>
</li>

</ul>
```

> Class active is for highlighting

You still need to set the variable on every page to mark them

```
{% extends "master.html" %}
{% set active_page = "menu1" %}
```

or

```
{% set active_page = "menu2" %}
```

Comment: the simplest yet best solution!

Comment: plus points from me!

Comment: You can avoid using `{% set active_page = "menu1" %}` if you use `request.path[1:]` --> `class="{{ 'active' if request.path[1:] == 'menu1' else '' }}" `

Comment: Simple and useful, it helps me

Answer (score 7):

For **jinja/flask/bootstrap** users:

If you define your nav like they did in the blog example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/
simply assign ids to your links that match your *url_for* arguments and you just need to modify the layout-template, the rest just works #magic.

```
<nav class="blog-nav">
  <a id="allposts"  class="blog-nav-item" href="{{ url_for('allposts')}}">All Posts</a>
  <a id="index"     class="blog-nav-item" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Index</a>
  <a id="favorites" class="blog-nav-item" href="{{ url_for('favorites')}}">Favorites</a>
</nav>
```

At the bottom of your base/layout template just add this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#{{request.endpoint}}").addClass("active"); })
</script>
```

and the right elements will be set active.

**EDIT:**
If you have a layout with  elements in a list, like this:

```
<nav class="blog-nav">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
        <a id="allposts"  class="blog-nav-item" href="{{ url_for('allposts')}}">All Posts</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="index"     class="blog-nav-item" href="{{ url_for('index')}}">Index</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="favorites" class="blog-nav-item" href="{{ url_for('favorites')}}">Favorites</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

use the  **parent()**  function to get the li element instead of the link.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#{{request.endpoint}}").parent().addClass("active"); })
</script>
```

Comment: While this is a valid option, it will not work in the case when the user disables JavaScript in the browser. I know, who does that? But it happens! As a result, you don't want to use JavaScript for things that can easily be handled by Jinja.

Comment: You are right, but then the functionality of the site is basically reduced to zero, as AJAX stops working, that is used to load most of the content.

Comment: AJAX is not a requirement. If you're using AJAX, chances are you aren't using Jinja either. You'll want to generate your HTML templates on the client side with a javascript templating engine, like Handlebars, to properly format the results from your AJAX requests.

Answer (score 4):

> we can make class active by using jinja if statements

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="{% if request.endpoint=='home' %}active{%endif %}"><a href="{{  url_for('home') }}">home</a></li>
     <li class="{% if request.endpoint=='add_client' %}active{%endif %}"><a href="{{  url_for('add_client') }}">Add Report</a></li>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked [@philmaweb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2601976/philmaweb)'s approach, but there's really no reason to require duplicating the endpoint in the id of each element.

*base.js:*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var scriptElement = $('#baseScript')[0];
    var path = scriptElement.getAttribute('data-path');
    $('a[href="'+path+'"]').addClass("active");
});
```

*base.html*

```
<script id="baseScript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/base.js') }}"
data-path="{{ request.path }}"></script>
```

Why not just put this script inline? You could, of course, but allowing inline JS is [a security nightmare](https://www.troyhunt.com/locking-down-your-website-scripts-with-csp-hashes-nonces-and-report-uri/). You should be using a CSP on your site (e.g. [Flask-Talisman](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman)) which will not allow inline JS. With `data-*` attributes, it's not hard to do this in a secure way.

NB: If you have multiple links leading to the same, current page and you want only ONE of them to be marked "active"—then this approach may not work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I tried different solution for this for the solution 1st by [Codegeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572562/codegeek) didn't work as I have multiple Ul and li under it so I just include my navbar in template.html

```
{% include 'sidebar.html' %}
```

then in Navbar file in the li class you can set active with help of "request.endpoint" but then again it will return you entire route instead use split and take last route name and set active if same for exmaple

```
 <li class="{% if request.endpoint.split('.')[1] == 'index' %} active {% else %}  {% endif %}">
```

`request.endpoint.split('.')[1]` will return the route eg localhost/example. You will get example which you can compare and use. If you won't split and use request.endpoint than you will get 'file.example' (entire route).

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS somewhere on your page:

`a[href $= {{ page_name|default("'/'"|safe) }}]{ [INSERT YOUR ACTIVE STYLING HERE] }`

Now, on each template define `page_name`, for example:

`{% extends "template.html" %}
 {% set page_name = "gallery" %}`

This seems much simpler and easier to build on, than other options.

EDIT:

Almost 1 year later I'm returning to make this a much simpler fix, because setting the page name on every page is pretty inefficient.

Instead create a function like so:

```py
@app.context_processor
def context_processor():
    out = {}
    out['request'] = request # Make sure you import request from flask
    return out
```

This will allow you to pass variables implicitly to jinja, in this case we are passing the request for access to `request.url_rule` which contains the route the user is accessing. In the previous version, we just change `{{ page_name|default("'/'"|safe) }}` to `"{{ request.url_rule|safe }}"`. Much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to have to define the ID in the child pages, as many of the links I have do not have a specific child template.

Using the `request.base_url` and if it matches the `_external` `url_for` the route, then render that nav item as active.

```html
{% set nav_items = [
    ("public.home", "Home"),
    ("public.downloads", "Downloads"),
    ("public.about", "About")
    ("account.login", "Login"),
 ]
 -%}

...

   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   {% for route, display_text in  nav_items %}
     <li class={% if request.base_url == url_for(route, _external=True) %}"nav-item active"{% else %}"nav-item"{% endif %}>
       <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for(route) }}">{{ display_text }}
     {% if request.base_url == url_for(route, _external=True) %}<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>{% endif %}
       </a>
     </li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Shout out to [@pablo-vilas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12585397/pablo-vilas)!  for his comment above.

## Most Simplistic & Dynamic:

Use `request.path[1:]` then make the == to the url_for path and your done,

- with the exception of the home `/` page, that will just be empty quotes `''`

> No Extra Setting or JavaScript customization required!

### Copy-Pasta Example:

```
...
<li class="nav-item btn btn-sm btn-dark"><a class="nav-link{{ 'active' if request.path[1:] == '' else ''}}" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-item btn btn-sm btn-dark"><a class="nav-link{{ 'active' if request.path[1:] == 'about' else ''}}" href="{{ url_for('about') }}">About</a></li>
<li class="nav-item btn btn-sm btn-dark"><a class="nav-link{{ 'active' if request.path[1:] == 'dashboard' else ''}}" href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}">About</a></li>
...
```