# How to add space inbetween nav items in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I was wondering if it is possible to add spacing between items in Bootstraps navbar to spread them out a little? Specifically if I could space out all nav-items left and right by at least 25px.

I have tried adding margin left and right to the class `.navbar-nav` and `.navbar-nav > a`, however it doesn't appear to change anything.

Thank you in advance!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light fixed-top p">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-
    target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-
    expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)
            </span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To separate two navbar areas in bootstrap4, I used this:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img src="logo.png" width="192" height="44" alt="">
        Bootstrap Navbar Demo
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link mx-3 active" href="/page1">Page 1</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link mx-3" href="/page2">Page 2</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link mx-3" href="/page2">Page 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link mx-3" href="/logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Basically the buttons have margins of `mx-3` to separate them a bit.  The `mr-auto` pushes the `logout` button to far right.

With https://stackoverflow.com/a/18600623/999943 this is pretty nice.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

`.navbar-nav > a` should be working fine to target the `.nav-item`s. In case it does not work, make sure that you apply the custom styles after you reference the `bootstrap.css`. By the way, Bootstrap uses padding applied to `.navbar-expand-{breakpoint} .navbar-nav .nav-link` to space out the items. Also the following should work fine:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-link {
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
```

Also, in case you don't mind to extend the markup, there are the handy [Spacing utility](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) classes available in Bootstrap. With those you can easily fine-tune your layout.
In the example below I used `.mx-3` on `.nav-item`s to increase their margin in horizontal direction to `1rem` on each side. Then applied `.ml-3` –margin-left– on the last item in order to have it’s right edge align with the rest of the layout.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light fixed-top p">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-
    target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-
    expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link mx-3" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)
            </span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link mx-3" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link mx-3" href="#">Pricing</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link ml-3" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the margin to the class **.navbar-nav > .nav-item** instead of **.navbar-nav > a**.

So you should do something like this.

```
.navbar-nav > .nav-item{
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
```