# Getting rails url or controller action that is being sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, controller, helper

How can I get the controller action or url that the page is going to land on? (not the one it's coming from)

e.g if i click `new_event_path`, can I know extract either of those?

Trying to implement a helper method for this

[Rails bootstrap nav tabs active while rendering via yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396129/rails-bootstrap-nav-tabs-active-while-rendering-via-yield)

For example in my view I have this `class=<%= path_set_active(['upcoming', 'past']) %>`

and in my helper method i have this

```
def path_set_active(array)
    'active' if (array).include?(controller.action_name)
    # binding.pry
end
```

This doesn't work because `controller.action_name` is not hit yet. If i do binding.pry it's saying it's coming from `home`. But it's going to hit the `upcoming` action. So how do i detect where the the request/controller is going?

Comment: I don't understand how this question is different than your other question you're linking to? I am marking it as a duplicate ... If it really is different, then please explain :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails bootstrap nav tabs active while rendering via yield](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396129/rails-bootstrap-nav-tabs-active-while-rendering-via-yield)

Comment: i'll update the question right now. it's slightly different because i'm stuck on how to call a method which i'm not sure if it exists..

Comment: I never found the answer to this but I did solve the issue with the first problem which is now answered.