# Assigning active class for bootstrap Nav-pills - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I have a blog section in my rails app and was wondering what a good way to handle assigning the CSS class `active` would be, based on the page that would be open.

Should this be done via `.erb` with `if` and `do` statements? It would need to reflect the category the post is in.

**Blog Category Table:**

```
create_table "blog_categories", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.integer "parent_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

**Posts Table Column:** `t.integer "category_id"` - This is stored  to relate to the `.id` of the cat.

My categories are represented with a `parent_id` of `NULL` and subcategories are those with a `parent_id` set to the `.id` of the main category.

Comment: You can take reference from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879169/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-navigation-to-show-active-link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by defining a function in your application_helper.rb

```
def active_class(path)
 "active" if current_page?(path)
end
```

`current_page?` method will return active if the user is on the same url as passed in path parameter. checkout its [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F).

Then in view you can use it like this.

```
<li class="<%= active_class new_user_session_path %>">
```

Comment: Is this better than including the code directly such as: `<%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>`?

Comment: Both are same logically, but defining a function is better in a sense it makes your code reusable and clean.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer you to use these helpers below one is for single path 
eg:

```
<li class="<%= active_class(first_path) %>">

def active_class(link_path)
 current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : ''
end
```

this one is for multiple array of links 
eg

```
<li class="<%= active_class_multiple([first_path, second_path]) %>">

# pass array of paths to get current page active link
def active_class_multiple(array)
  array.include?(request.path) ? 'active' : ''
end
```