# Javascript not executing in rails view partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nav

I used bootstrap navbar , but I need to change the active class on different nav-item click, but the active class is not being applied/added when other nav-item is clicked , it stays static.

some extract of partial view is->

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light  fixed-top" id="topheader">
    <section class="container d-flex">
      <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 a">Project Manager</span>

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active" id="project-nav" onclick= "change2()">
          <%= link_to "Project", projects_path, class: "nav-link" %>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="user-nav" onclick= "change()">
          <%= link_to "user", users_path, class: "nav-link" %>
        </li>

      </ul>
```

so I tried to implement js by writing in application.js , but it didn't work

```
$(".navbar-nav .nav-item").on("click", function(){
   $(".navbar-nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

I also tried

```
function change(){
  document.getElementById("project-nav").className.replace(" active", "");
  document.getElementById("user-nav").className += " active ";
}
```

But the class is not changing- it seems that the onclick event is not being executed at all

Comment: have you added on-click function and javascript code in document.ready function?

Comment: I have given all relevant code I have tried

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors? If you add a an alert, do you see that alert when the page loads? Do you find your JavaScript code by view page source and opening the JavaScript file? What happens when you go add a break point in the developer tools -> debugger?

Comment: Have you made sure to require `jquery` and `jquery-ujs` into your application.js file? Your first example won't work unless you do that, and wrap the click listener in a `$(document).ready()` check

Comment: yes i have jquery and jquery-ujs

Comment: yes js is working @iJK  I also checked with an alert box which is working

Comment: @Achy97 Did you try adding a breakpoint in your JS via developer tools? Does it catch? Can you find the class "nav-item" in your page source? I would remove the onclick calls in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is causing the issue is this:

```
<%= link_to "Project", projects_path, class: "nav-link" %>
```

and also this:

```
<%= link_to "user", users_path, class: "nav-link" %>
```

So, when you click on the `nav-item` it will actually redirect to `projects_path`, or `users_path`, it depends on which link you clicked.

This code:

```
$(".navbar-nav .nav-item").on("click", function(){
  $(".nav-item").not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Will working if you have this code structure:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item"> Project </li>
  <li class="nav-item" > User </li>
</ul>
```

So, if you want to add the class `active` only to the active link in the navbar, you can do this:

1. HTML file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light  fixed-top" id="topheader">
  <section class="container d-flex">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1 a">Project Manager</span>

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <%= link_to "Project", projects_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <%= link_to "user", users_path, class: "nav-link" %>
      </li>
          .....
     </ul>
  </section>
</nav>
```

2. In the JS file:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {
  $('.nav-item a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active');
});
```

References:

[How to get Twitter-Bootstrap navigation to show active link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879169/how-to-get-twitter-bootstrap-navigation-to-show-active-link)

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: thank you so much for putting in such an effort, indeed it worked

Comment: can you please tell how can i make one of my nav item set active when the page loads?

Comment: It’s my pleasure. This code should do that. When the page loads, it’s supposed to find the .nav-item with anchor tag that has a particular path, and add class .active to the .nav-item. Did you give it a try?

Comment: Yes, but no item is selected when the page is loaded first, otherwise its working fine @violeta

Comment: Do you have this for your root path: ```<li class="nav-item">
  <%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "nav-link" %> ?
</li>```